# Status menu using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I'm writing my application and I need to have a status menu that shows the current state of a verification function. The function for the verification is CPU heavy and needs to work so I cannot print my status all the time. Currently this is my code:

```
HANDLE t = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)thread_test, 0, 0, 0);
int c;
while (true)
{
    printf("[s]tatus, [e]xit => ");
    c = getch();
    putchar(c);
    if (c == 's') {
        putchar('\n');
        is_visible = true;
    }
    else if (c == 'e')
        ExitProcess(0);
    else putchar('\n');
}
```

And this is the code for `thread_test()`:

```
bool is_visible = false;
void thread_test() {
    while (true) {
        if (is_visible == true) printf("This is status.\n");
    }
}
```

Now how can I make the `thread_test()` function display this message only once and then continue without showing anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use `std::thread` over `CreateThread` whenever possible

Comment: From [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx): *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread; this requires the use of the multithreaded version of the CRT. If a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions."* Why did you decide that reading documentation were a waste of your time?

Comment: Ever heard of [finite state machines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)? Seems relevant here. No need for threads as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How would I use them here?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) post a [mcve]  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: suggest learning (and using) C, such that `if (is_visible == true)` becomes: `if (is_visible)`

Comment: strongly suggest using `getchar()` rather than `getch()`

Comment: what happens when the user enters something other than 's' or 'e'?

Comment: @user3629249 it is not interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

*how can I make the thread_test() function display this message only once and then continue without showing anything?*

suggest replacing:

```
if (is_visible == true) printf("This is status.\n");
```

with

```
if ( is_visible ) 
{ 
    printf( "This is status.\n" ); 
    is_visible = false; 
}
```